# When did the Buddha get angry?

Tags: gautama-buddha, anger

I wish to know the circumstances where/when Buddha ever got angry and acted upon that anger. Thanks for your time. Love.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As others have said, the Buddha would not have gotten angry. There are however, suttas which show his sternness such as [Kucchivikara-vatthu: The Monk with Dysentery](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/vin/mv/mv.08.26.01-08.than.html) In this sutta, the Buddha and Venerable Ananda come across a very sick and neglected monk lying in his own filth in a monastery. The Buddha shows compassion and along with Ananda cleans the sick monk. But then he calls together the rest of the monks and gives them a talking to about taking responsibility for each other. While we can't know the tone the Buddha would have used; given the situation and the apparent lack of compassion shown by the monks; we can imagine it would have been stern.

The Buddha used the term "worthless man" in the [Mahatanhasankhaya Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.038.than.html) and others and the term "foolish man" in the [Alagaddupama Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.022.nypo.html) and others.

Of course, as an enlightened being, none of this was done in anger. The Buddha would have known the best way to speak to each to make them understand and sometimes this would not have been in a gentle tone.

There is another question on the site ["Was the Buddha Harsh?"](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/8804/was-the-buddha-harsh) which has many more examples of this type of necessary speech.

Answer (score 11):

Anger is eradicated at the 3rd stage([Anagami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An%C4%81g%C4%81mi)) of enlightenment. Lord Buddha is fully enlightened. It is impossible to make him or any other being who has reached or passed the stage of Anagami, angry.

Answer (score 4):

i dont recall in any sutta even before the evening of enlightment that Buddha got angry.  IMO, The strongest/most firm words of his teaching was when Buddha corrected a monk (i dont recall name) who still taught others about existence of permanent soul (or transmigrating Vinnana) even after was told about the impermanent of vinnana.

Comment: his name was [Sāti](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.038.than.html). I thought he was [pretty harsh](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/8804/was-the-buddha-harsh) myself.

Comment: yes!!!!  thanks.  What became of him?  Did he reach higher level of Dhamma later?

Comment: just as Robin said, since Buddha knew the level of 5 strengths in all beings, his teaching style and words were perfect and for the benefit of his students.

Answer (score 2):

The Buddha cannot get angry. Thus, he never acts upon it. The Buddha is completely liberated from suffering.