# Did Buddha ever get angry after enlightenment?

Tags: buddha

I'm exploring the nature of anger, so want to know.

Comment: As well as [When did the Buddha get angry?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/9750/254), see also [Was the Buddha harsh?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/8804/254) and [Did the Buddha ever 'thunder' during a Fire Sermon?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/4117/254)

Answer (score 1):

Anger(Patigha/Byāpāda) is uprooted at the stage of [Anagami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An%C4%81g%C4%81mi). So it's technically impossible for any being who has attained Anagami or above to get angry, let alone the Buddha.

Comment: Can you cite some reference on this?

Comment: Read the fetters cut off by Anagamis. Linked it.